# Digital microphone needed for T60p, running Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, microphone

I need to buy a good external microphone to use on my IBM/Lenovo T60p, which is running Ubuntu 16.04. Will the drivers in the OS installed support any microphone?

Answer (score 0):

All generic USB audio devices are supported. Some non-standard devices may only work with proprietary drivers and software in the OSes supported by the manufacturer.